# Screens Delete Themselves

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

So I'm attempting to make a start file which launches several screens each with their respective script. Looks a bit like:

```
cd /home/foo/
screen -dmS foo bash -c '/run.sh'
echo Started Foo
```

run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    java -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -server -jar foo.jar -o true
    sleep 5
done;
```

Now if I do screen -ls right after I run it, the screen shows up. However if I check a second later, the screens gone. Am I doing something wrong or is this the typical behavior?

Comment: What does `run.sh` do? Does it stay running or does the script terminate?

Comment: It's a while true script that keeps a jar running. Added it's contents to the question.

Comment: does `/run.sh` exist? is it executable? maybe mistype of `./run.sh` ? what happens if you just exectue `bash -c '/run.sh'`?

Comment: Both produce no result.

Comment: you should try executing `screen -dmLS foo bash -c '/run.sh'` . `-L` option turns on logging and outputs log into `screenlog.0`. see that log for what's happening.

Comment: Woo, found out what was wrong. At least I wasn't the only one who didn't see it. Basically there's no "sh" in front of the run.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `sh` to the start of the command because I didn't make it executable.